# How to get array value dynamically

Tags: php, arrays

I'm not sure if there is such a function, but I'd expect it to do the following:
`get_array_value($array, $chain);` where `$array` is the array to search for the value, and `$chain` is an array that contains information which value to retrieve.

Example usage: if `$chain = array('key1', 'key2', 'key3');`, then the function should return `$array['key1']['key2']['key3'];`

Is there anything similar out there already and if not, how could I achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

## UPDATE:

Huh, the intended result should be a single value, not an array. So I could use it like `echo get_array_value($array, $chain);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$cloneArray = $array;  // clone it for future usage
foreach($chain as $value)
{
   $cloneArray =  $cloneArray[$value];
}

var_dump($cloneArray);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function resolve ($array, $chain) {
    return empty($chain) 
        ? $array;
        :resolve($array[array_shift($chain)], $chain);
}
```

Thats the very short form. You must verify, that all keys, that you want to resolve, exists (and such).